# s3fs suddenly stopped working in Google Colab with error "AttributeError: module 'aiobotocore' has no attribute 'AioSession'"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, botocore, python-s3fs

Yesterday the following cell sequence in Google Colab would work.

[image]

(I am using [colab-env](https://github.com/apolitical/colab-env) to import environment variables from Google Drive.)

This morning, when I run the same code, I get the following error.

[image]

It appears to be a new issue with s3fs and aiobotocore.  I have some experience with Google Colab and library version dependency issues that I have previously solved by upgrading libraries in a particular order:

```
!pip install --upgrade library_name
```

But I am a bit stuck this morning with this one.  It is affecting all of my Google Colab notebooks so I thought that perhaps it is affecting others who are using data stored in Amazon AWS S3 with Google Colab.

The version of s3fs that gets installed is 2021.07.0, which appears to be the latest.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this might be related https://github.com/dask/s3fs/issues/514

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a transient error that has been resolved.

Comment: im limited to s3fs version `2021.7.0` because of some dependency issues and needing to support python 3.7. its unfortunate that they dont fix the issue with this specific version of aiobotocore

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indeed, the breakage was with the release of aiobotocore 1.4.0 (today, 20 Aug 2021), which is fixed in release 2021.08.0 of s3fs, also today.

Comment: AMAZING!  What a fast fix!  I can confirm it is all working again. Thank you and thank you for all your work on s3fs.  I ❤️  that library.  Thank you @mdurant

Comment: I have s3fs==2021.5.0 fixed on my requirements, how did this break from one day to the other? are transitive dependencies not fixed?

Comment: Generally no, packages rely on their dependencies being well behaved, so you are free to upgrade where other packages might require it. Aiobotocore changes too often, we have now decided to pin the version.